# base 64 byte array not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, firefox, base64

I am using ASP.NET MVC with jquery and SQL SERVER.

I have one page where I got base 64 from controller side to ajax success and pass it to the browser's new tab and it will show me pdf file:

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data.bytedata);
```

The interesting thing is in firefox it is working fine and in chrome as well it's working fine but since last 2 or 3 days in chrome it is not working just giving me some kind of bytedata that is not working in chrome and in firefox as well.

Might be problem is the bytedata coming from controller in chrome is invalid that's why it is not running in firefox as well and in chrome as well but same page same call bytedata coming from controller in firefox is running fine in chrome as well and in firefox too.

Don't know how to distinguish this problem.

Comment: it seems you are saying it works and doesn't work at the same time!! I must be reading your question wrong as well as incorrectly

Comment: Let's take a step back and try to rewrite all this in understandable statements. Your current workflow is ***1.** You send bytedata from browsers, **2.** store it on server. **3.** get back this data from other browsers.* Now the **problem** is that *since a few days, data sent from chrome browsers are corrupted (even FF can't open handle these data).* Is that all correct ? If so, is chrome able to handle data sent by FF ? Why do you send b64 data instead of real binary pdf files ?

Comment: @JaromandaX My meaning is if I run my application in firefox and copy that url of base64 and paste it in chrome it will run but if I do visa versa from chrome to firefox. It is not running in chrome and the same link is also not run in firefox. This happens since last 3 days ago.

Comment: @Kaiido yes your understanding is correct and yes I have to send direct coming  bytearray as base64 to new tab because it is already done I just have to resolve this error I do not have rights to change the flow or code sir.

Comment: Héhé "fix the bugs but don't change the code". Easier to change the job ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido he he he correct but the code was running till now but nowadays getting this error so need to solve and if not than I must have solid reason to change the code than I will have rights to change the code. Please let me know any help you can do for this would be nice. :)

Comment: I can't help you more than by recommending you to rewrite your question clearly, try to add an [MCVE] so we can reproduce the issue, if not possible, try to add the minimal broken data from chrome, and the same minimal but working data from FF. One thing that comes to my mind for a sudden change would be that some plugin may have been installed (e.g ad-block plugins are kown to not allow dataURI files in js-opened windows), but that's a really long shot...

Comment: @Kaiido got the way posted the answer thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it where my code stop working in chrome.

Actually Chrome has just recently released one new version on 2nd Aug:

**Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

and it stopped working in above version.

My code runs perfectly fine in below version i.e. upto

**Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

I have reported this issue to Chrome let's see how they resolve this.

### UPDATED SOLUTION:

Use iframe and load base64 inside that:

```
window.open("<iframe src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(data.bytedata) + "'></iframe>")
```